# Mathematica 10.1.0.0 (OS X) high CPU usage even for empty notebook

Tags: front-end, bugs, system-performance

**Bug fixed in 10.1.0** (see answer for details)

---

Since update to 10.1.0.0 Mathematica has a high CPU usage even when no evaluation is running (even for empty notebook opened). I am running OS X Yosemite 10.10.3 on the following configuration:

- Model Name:   MacBook Pro
- Model Identifier: MacBookPro5,5
- Processor Name:   Intel Core 2 Duo
- Processor Speed:  2,26 GHz
- Number of Processors: 1
- Total Number of Cores:    2
- L2 Cache: 3 MB
- Memory:   8 GB
- Bus Speed:    1,07 GHz
- Boot ROM Version: MBP55.00AC.B03
- SMC Version (system): 1.47f2

In[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iXFg.png):= SystemInformation["Kernel", "ReleaseID"]
Out[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iXFg.png)= "10.1.0.0 (5292907, 2015032401)"

My colleague reports the same on similar machine. Is this a bug?

[image: Activity Monitor screenshot. There is a single empty notebook opened in Mathmatica.]

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:bugs] tag when posting new questions.

Comment: same here. Mathematica v10.1 on Mac OS X 10.10.3.

Comment: What version number does `SystemInformation["Kernel", "ReleaseID"]` report?

Comment: I can confirm that this is a bug in Mathematica 10.1.0 on OSX, and appears to mostly happen on older MacBookPro machines (with Core 2 Duo processors). We do so far not have a workaround, but are actively working on a fix.

Comment: @StefanR I noticed this might be related to java, since the java process called by WolframKernel soars around 100% cpu usage. And it's not only for older MBP models, mine is the late-2014 rMBP model with Intel i7 processors that is suffering this problem as well.

Comment: Same for me (MMA 10.1.0 with OS X 10.9.5 MacBook Pro Core 2 duo). This problem was already mentionned by @xslittlegrass in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2234?m=20889593#20889593).

Comment: There is mistake in the title, please change it with the correct (10.1.0) Mathematica version.

Comment: @sunt05 We believe this is a race condition in MathLink, which seems to happen when the FE tries to auto-login to WolframCloud on startup.

Comment: I just want to chime in with a confirmation. I've been having this issue since 10.1.0.0 was released. I've emailed Wolfram and gotten no response. But for now i'm solving my problem by simply redownloading 10.0.2 and getting back to work.

Comment: same here on a core2 duo mid-2010 macbook pro. cannot use 10.1 for now.

Comment: @StefanR Now it is 100% reproducible for me each time I launch MMA, since the startup screen is automatically displayed. At least with 1 WolframKernel process, or sometimes with 2 WolframKernel + 1 reqpwd.exe process  (i am on OSX). Any fix  ?

Comment: @SquareOne Yes we have a fix. Please contact `support@wolfram.com` for details.

Comment: @StefanR Good news !! Maybe you can post this important information as an answer to this post, as many users are waiting for it. BTW what kind of fix is it ? (a new version to download ?)

Comment: @StefanR It would be useful if you could post the info about the fix here. Is it a new version? Or do we just have to downgrade to 10.0.2?

Comment: Not just Core 2 Duo.  I see it on my Core i7 (I7-3667U).  Mathematica pegs one core at 100% immediately upon launch, without even starting up a kernel.

Answer (score 12):

This is a bug in Mathematica 10.1.0 on OSX, and seems to primarily, but not exclusively, affect older MacBookPro machines with Core 2 Duo processors.

We have identified the cause and devised a fix. Unfortunately, the fix is not simple, and requires replacement of a few key components. We have created a patched version of Mathematica 10.1.0 which is completely identical except for the aforementioned components.

For now, we are only handing this patched build out to customers that have run into this issue. So if you are affected, please contact `support@wolfram.com` for further instructions.

**Update**
The Mathematica 10.1.0 for OSX installer in the User Portal is being replaced with the installer for the patched version in the next couple of days. The way to tell the difference is that the DMG disk image for the patched version has the MD5 checksum `c347b7e1f79dad90a98859037cac1ccf`.

Comment: I emailed support and got the patched version.  Indeed it fixed the problem.

Comment: Why not give it a new version number? This seems bound to confuse people (like I was).

Comment: @PontusGranström To make sure we got the fix out as soon as possible. Changing the version number can subtly affect a surprising number of things, both in Mathematica and in the build system we use, and can introduce bugs.